# Multiple Listviews on tab2 control

Tags: listview, tabcontrol, autohotkey

Here I have a problem with multiple `listview` controls on a `tab2` control.

In my gui, I have a `tab2` control where three of the tabs each have 1 listview control.

My problem is that when I use `LV_GetText()`, I can't find any way of distinguishing which `listview` to fetch from.

To compound the problem, there is no way for `LV_Add()` to distinguish between the listviews either.

Normally, you only have to distinguish between gui windows with `mygui:default` but there doesn't appear to be this option for `listview` controls.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to specify which listview.  [It actually mentions this in the docs, too.](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/ListView.htm#BuiltIn)

Basically, what you do is change the default listview.  You can't really *direct* your functions to a particular listview, but if you change the default listview, you can then operate on it.  Once changed, all subsequent commands operate on the new default.

You change it like this:

```
Gui, ListView, ListViewName
```

or like this, if you need to distinguish also between gui windows:

```
Gui, 3:ListView, ListViewName
```

Here is a sample.  Paste this into a script file and run it to see that it does work.

---

### Basic Methodology

```
#SingleInstance,force
gosub, SHOWGUI
return

SHOWGUI:
    gui, mainui:new, hwndmainui, ListViews On Tab2
    gui, add, tab2, vtabs, one|two|three|four
        gui, tab, one
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview1 gListView1Events +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "bob", "harry")
            LV_Add("", "first", "listview")
        gui, tab, two
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview2 gListView2Events +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "george", "harvey")
            LV_Add("", "second", "listview")
        gui, tab, three
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview3 gListView3Events +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "michael", "richard")
            LV_Add("", "third", "listview")     
        gui, tab, four
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview4 gListView4Events +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "harold", "marcel")
            LV_Add("", "fourth", "listview")        
    gui, show
RETURN


REPORT:
    LV_GetText(firstcol, A_EventInfo, 1)
    LV_GetText(secondcol, A_EventInfo, 2)
    msgbox, %firstcol% : %secondcol%
RETURN

ListView1Events:
    gui, mainui:listview, listview1
    if(A_GuiEvent == "Normal"){ 
        gosub, REPORT
    }   
RETURN

ListView2Events:
    gui, mainui:listview, listview2
    if(A_GuiEvent == "Normal"){ 
        gosub, REPORT
    }   
RETURN

ListView3Events:
    gui, mainui:listview, listview3
    if(A_GuiEvent == "Normal"){ 
        gosub, REPORT
    }   
RETURN

ListView4Events:
    gui, mainui:listview, listview4
    if(A_GuiEvent == "Normal"){ 
        gosub, REPORT
    }   
RETURN
```

---

### A Better Way

Actually, [there is a better, not-so-clumsy way, thanks go *garry*](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3656#p19069) to handle the multiple listviews.

In this method, the trick is to name the listviews with the same name plus a sequential number: `listview1, listview2, listview3...`

This way there can be a single gLabel for the event handler: `gui, mainui:listview, listview%Tabnumber%`

```
;-------- http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3656 ---
MODIFIED=20140531
Tabnumber:=1
    gui, mainui:new, hwndmainui, ListViews On Tab2
    gui,add, Tab2, gtabchange vTabnumber AltSubmit, one|two|three|four
        gui,tab, one
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview1 gListViewEvents +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "bob", "harry")
            LV_Add("", "first", "111111111")
            gosub,width1
        gui,tab, two
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview2 gListViewEvents +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "george", "harvey")
            LV_Add("", "second", "222222")
            gosub,width1
        gui, tab, three
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview3 gListViewEvents +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "michael", "richard")
            LV_Add("", "third", "33333333")
            gosub,width1
        gui, tab, four
            gui,add, listview, r5 vlistview4 gListViewEvents +altsubmit -multi, col1|col2
            LV_Add("", "harold", "marcel")
            LV_Add("", "fourth", "44444")
            gosub,width1
    gui, show
gosub,tabchange
RETURN

mainuiGuiclose:
exitapp

width1:
  T1=70
   T2=140
   LV_ModifyCol(1,T1)
   LV_ModifyCol(2,T2)
   LV_ModifyCol(2,"Integer")
return

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
tabchange:
  GuiControlGet, Tabnumber
Return
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ListViewEvents:
   gui, mainui:listview, listview%Tabnumber%
    if(A_GuiEvent == "Normal"){
    LV_GetText(firstcol, A_EventInfo, 1)
    LV_GetText(secondcol, A_EventInfo, 2)
    msgbox, %firstcol% : %secondcol%
    }
RETURN
```